# GCController Swift 2 How to detect button press

Tags: controller, user-controls, sprite-kit, swift2

I wish to make my 2D-platform game I'm developing respond to buttons pressed on MFi controllers. I've been hung up on one problem for hours. I'm doing essentially what the Apple Developer Guide for the GameController framework instructs me to do, though the code in the guide is in Objective-C, not Swift (come on, Apple). I can't understand what I'm doing wrong and I have a feeling that the answer will be so simple, but I can't understand it. My only explanation is a bug in Xcode 7 Beta. Anyways, here's my code:

```
if GCController.controllers().count >= 1 {
if GCController().gamepad!.buttonA.pressed {
jump()
```

}

}

When I run the app on my iPhone it runs well, but when I unplug my iPhone from my Mac and try to use it with my Logitech PowerShell, it crashes upon the scene being presented.

By the way, that's not really how I format my code. I will have no Wi-Fi confection for a few more weeks and my carrier doesn't support an iPhone acting as a Personal Hotspot, so I have to use my iPhone to post this, therefore it looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

The profile `gamepad` is a property of an individual controller, not the controller array.  You need to do something like:

```
if let controller = GCController.controllers().first {
    if controller.gamepad!.buttonA.pressed {
        jump()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the `pressedChangedHandler` and call your `jump()` from there.  You'll need to do that in the `controllerDidConnect` notification so you'll have a reference to a controller:

```
@objc class func controllerDidConnect(notification: NSNotification) {

    let controller = notification.object as! GCController

    controller.gamepad?.buttonA.pressedChangedHandler = { (element: GCControllerElement, value: Float, pressed: Bool) in

        if pressed {
            jump()
       }    
    }
}
```